# Convert a list of delimited strings to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have an input list of the form

```py
c = ['a|b', 'c|d', 'e|f']
```

which I want to convert to `dict` like

```py
c_dict = {'b': 'a', 'd': 'c', 'f': 'e'}
```

I could do this with a comprehension like

```py
c_dict = {el.split('|')[1]: el.split('|')[0] for el in c}
```

But the repeated `el.split` looks ugly. Is there a more succinct one-liner to get the desired result?

Comment: `{k: v for v, k in (i.split('|') for i in c)}`

Comment: `dict(reversed(i.split('|')) for i in c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it for the one-liner case:

```
print(dict(reversed(i.split('|')) for i in ['a|b', 'c|d', 'e|f']))
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is to split the entries by `|` and take second value as key and first as value for the dictionary. So basically you can do this:

```py
def list_to_dict(entries):
    res = {}
    for entry in entries:
        item = entry.split('|')
        res[item[1]] = item[0]
    return res
```

or a shorter version would be:

```py
def list2dict(entries):
    return dict(reversed(x.split('|')) for x in entries)
```

Answer (score 1):

As `dict([[1,2]])={1: 2}` we can use this as:

```python
c = ['a|b', 'c|d', 'e|f']
c_dict = dict(t.split("|")[::-1] for t in c)
```

edited by point of @deceze

Comment: The `[]` around the `for .. in` expression is superfluous and inefficient…